# bottom to top animation example

Tags: iphone

I need to show the next image with bottom up animation in uiviewcontroller.

How can i do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the next images' frame to below the current one (just off screen), then in an animation block, change its frame to take the place of the other image view, at which point you can remove the old image view from its superview.